# Default C++ standard is c++98 in Apple Clang++ 13

Tags: c++, macos, clang++

I am new to macOS. I have a m1 Macbook ruing macOS Monterey. I am compiling and running c++ code in terminal.

The clang++ version is:

```
clang++ --version                                                                                                                
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

when I compile any file without specifying `-std=c++xx`, clang++ will use c++98 as default. However, I checked the manual using `man clang++`, where it says "*The default C++ language standard is gnu++14.*"

I wonder is there a way to set the default c++ standard as c++14 instead of c++98 (I don't want to use `alias`).

ps. I checked a lot posts, and they just confuse me more. Some people say that the apple clang just use c++98 as default, some say it is not.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The best way is to not manually invoke the compiler, use a proper build system and use the build systems options for setting the c++ standard