# List initialization returns semicolon error

Tags: c++, macos, clang

I'm trying to compile the following C++ code on Visual Studio Code, using the Mac clang compiler.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int x { 5 };
    std::cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

However, this returns an error, on the line of the list initialization: `int x{ 5 };`. Specifically, it says I need to insert a semicolon after the x.

I don't get what's wrong with this code, it works fine on an online compiler. How do I fix this?

Running `man clang` in the Terminal and skimming through, I found this:

```
The default C++ language standard is gnu++14.
```

**UPDATE:** I ran `clang++ main.cpp` in the compiler and it returned that semicolon error. This isn't a problem with VSCode, so I'll remove that tag.

Here's the error:

```
main.cpp:3:10: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    int x { 5 };
         ^
         ;
1 error generated.
```

Comment: did you actually try to compile, or is this only a message from the IDE?

Comment: Your code seems ok to me!

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number There's a "Run C/C++ file" button in VSCode. It compiles the code using clang and then runs it in the debug console. EDIT: Oop, it actually says clang++. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: "... then runs it in the debug console." so it does compile without compiler errors?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The semicolon error is the only error returned while compiling, if I don't use a list initialization in my code, it works.

Comment: I guess I might need to try compiling from the terminal and see if it's a problem with the compiler. I'll try doing that and then tell you if it works or not.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I ran `clang++ main.cpp` and it returned that semicolon error. It's probably a compiler problem. How do I fix this? I'm on a Mac.

Comment: better include the complete compiler error message in the question. The problem tab only displays a summary, that often omits important information that is present in the compiler error message. Moreover, if you can get same error on the console, consider this [Why should i not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: The manual page is wrong (for some odd reason, Apple do not keep the man page in sync with their compiler). The default language standard is (as far as I know) c++03. Add `-std=c++11` or something more recent.

Comment: Possibly relevant question (the man page is mentioned there as well): [Default C++ standard is c++98 in Apple Clang++ 13](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71670730/580083).

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you so much! That solves the problem. Do you know how to configure that for VSCode?

Comment: @MarekR I know posting images of code is generally frowned upon, but I've included the code as text, used a good alt text, and I needed it to show how the error looks like.

Comment: Errors also should be copy paste as text as [described in link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Same reasons. Check "output" tab. In general this rules applies for any kind of text: code, logs, errors, tasks descriptions, input data, output data, .... .

Comment: @Tyrcnex Sorry, I don't use VSCode. Check the documentation.

Comment: @MarekR Alright fine, I removed the image.

Comment: @molbdnilo Oh alright, thanks for info though!

Comment: This was just for the future question.