Unable to compile c++ code on OSX because a lib is throwing an error about version
I am trying to build c++ code that uses re2 lib from google but it's throwing me an error:

/usr/local/Cellar/abseil/20240722.0/include/absl/base/policy_checks.h:79:2: error: "C++ versions less than C++14 are not supported."

The code is super simple, it's literally a hello world testing JNI:
#include "HelloWorldJNI.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <re2/re2.h>

/*
 * Class:     HelloWorldJNI
 * Method:    sayHello
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL HelloWorldJNI_sayHello (JNIEnv* env, jobject thisObject) {
    std::cout << "Hello from C++ !!" << std::endl;
}

The code compiles if I remove re2 but I want to use it in my test to execute regex tests.
When I run g++ version it shows that I am running 15.0:
➜  g++ --version
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin23.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

I have tried to reinstall g++, gcc, abseil using homebrew but none works.
Any idea how to make it works on OSX?
edit: I am trying to compile with
g++ -c -fPIC -I${JAVA_HOME}/include -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/darwin HelloWorldJNI.cpp -o HelloWorldJNI.o


You need to set the C++ Language Standard (via a compilation switch) to at least -std=c++14 (or -std=c++17, -std=c++20).  Note that by default "Apple clang" targets a really old version of the C++ Standard. See also (old but relevant) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71670730/default-c-standard-is-c98-in-apple-clang-13

Make sure you are compiling with C++14 or later.  Put this in your code (before the #include directives) to ensure C++14 or later: #if __cplusplus < 201402L #error C++14 or later required #endif

@Eljay it throws me the error message on #error. Probably it's a wrong version from my compiler.

@RichardCritten how I set that? Im super new to c++

We will have to wait for someone with OSX experience.  To help them please add how you are currently building the project to the question (eg cmake and/or any build files).

Change g++ -c -fPIC -I${JAVA_HOME}/include -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/darwin HelloWorldJNI.cpp -o HelloWorldJNI.o to g++ -std=c++14 -c -fPIC -I${JAVA_HOME}/include -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/darwin HelloWorldJNI.cpp -o HelloWorldJNI.o to enable C++14 mode

Post edit, just add the C++ Standard directive by the to the command g++ -std=c++14 -c ......

Apple clang by default uses C++98 as C++ standard (in case of gcc it depends on version of gcc). So you have to change build settings explicitly -std=c++14. Now instead compiling manually, you should use some build manger or build manager generator (cmake for example).

Probably it's a wrong version from my compiler. Not exactly in this case. In this case the problem is the default c++ standard for clang++ on macOS is currently old regardless of the version of the compiler. You need to set the standard via the command line argument to fix this problem caused by the old standard being the default.
